# Website tab with database table as a content

Tags: php, dynamic, html-table

I am building a webpage with 3 tabs on every tab contain a table that will look like this that I extracted on a database table.

```
ID|    Case|  Name| Document| Date
 ----------------------------------------------
 1     233    alex    ITR      2015-1-1
 2     233    alex    ITR      2015-1-1
 3     233    alex    NULL     0000-0-0
 4     234    ben     COC      2015-3-3
 5     234    ben     VAT      2015-3-3
 6     234    ben     NULL     0000-0-0
```

on every tab it's different sql query to display the table. I already got the sql formula and I know basic PHP to show it on a table, just don't know how to load it in a html tab. Here is my code so far

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sample.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css">
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                            <<?php
                //conection: 
                $link = mysqli_connect("sssss","xxxxxxxxxxxxx","yyyyyyyyyyyyyy","xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
                //consultation: 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT 
                where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ORIGINAL_DEADLINE)>1;
                " or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 
                //execute the query. 
                $result = $link->query($query); 

                echo" <center> <table border = 3>
                <tr>
                <th>App Number</th>
                <th>Spoc Assigned</th>
                <th>Borrower Name</th>
                <th>App Finish Date</th>
                <th>Developer & Project</th>
                <th>Collateral Address Details</th>
                <th>Deferred Document</th>
                <th>Deferred Type</th>
                <th>Original Deadline</th>
                <th>Date Completed</th>
                <th>SPOC Remarks</th>
                <th>File Location</th>
                <th>JUW MA Remarks</th>
                <th>COSU Remarks</th>
                <th>SMU Notes</th>
                </tr></center>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";




                }
                mysqli_close($link);
                ?>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just do as you did with the first tab? and then just alter it to fetch the tab 2's content? make a second (and third and so on) query fetching the data and place it like you have in the first tab? (While I know this isn't the prettiest method it should be within OP's grasp)

Comment: Easy solution have an iframe in each tab, when you display tab the iframe loads different script.php for that tab, same origin and you can make the iframe seamless so wouldn't look any different

Comment: You can release the `$result` using `$result->close();` and then run a second Query from the same `$link`. I would also stick to either OOS or Procedural in your code. Just looks better than switching between both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few fixes in your code and some suggestions:

```
<div class="tab-content">
     <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
     <?php
     //conection: 
     $link = new mysqli("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx");
     if($link->connect_errno){
          printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
          exit();
     } 
     //consultation: 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ORIGINAL_DEADLINE)>1"; 
     //execute the query. 
     if($result = $link->query($query)){
          echo "<table border=3>\r\n";
          echo "<tr>\r\n";
          echo "<th>App Number</th>";
          echo "<th>Spoc Assigned</th>";
          echo "<th>Borrower Name</th>";
          echo "<th>App Finish Date</th>";
          echo "<th>Developer & Project</th>";
          echo "<th>Collateral Address Details</th>";
          echo "<th>Deferred Document</th>";
          echo "<th>Deferred Type</th>";
          echo "<th>Original Deadline</th>";
          echo "<th>Date Completed</th>";
          echo "<th>SPOC Remarks</th>";
          echo "<th>File Location</th>";
          echo "<th>JUW MA Remarks</th>";
          echo "<th>COSU Remarks</th>";
          echo "<th>SMU Notes</th>";
          echo "</tr>\r\n";

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
          }
          $results->close();
          echo "</table>\r\n";
        } else {
          printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
        ?>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p>
            <?php
            // Perform next SQL Query
            if($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM caseTickets")){
                 echo "<table>\r\n";
                 echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Case</th><th>Name</th><th>Document</th><th>Date</th></tr>\r\n";
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                      echo "<tr><td>{$row['ID']}</td><td>{$row['Case']}</td><td>{$row['Name']}</td><td>{$row['Document']}</td><td>{$row['Date']}</td></tr>\r\n";
                 }
                 echo "</table>\r\n";
                 $result->close();
            }  else {
                 printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
            }
            ?>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>
            <?php
            // Perform next SQL Query
            ?>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>
            <?php
            // Perform next SQL Query
            ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$link->close();
?>
```

If you're feeling adventurous: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php